# Compute partial derivative w.r.t initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could anyone help me on the following problem? Thank you very much!

Define $X: \mathcal{R} \times \mathcal{R} \rightarrow \mathcal{R}$ by:

$$\frac{dX}{dt}(t,x_0)=X(t,x_0)+\sin(X^2(t,x_0)),$$

$X(0,x_0)=x_0.$

Question: Find $\frac{\partial X}{\partial x_0}(t,0).$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following I interpreted your total derivative with respect to $t$ as a partial derivative. Willie explained in a comment that it might be intended to signify that $x_0$ is a parameter. There's no substantial difference between those two interpretations, so I'll leave the answer in my original notation, which considers $X$ as a function of two variables.

It's not clear to me what the subscript on $x_0$ is for, since $x$ doesn't occur anywhere without that subscript; I'll just write $x$ instead to simplify things.

I'll assume that we can exchange the partial derivatives with respect to $t$ and $x$; I think this follows from the [Cauchy–Kowalevski theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Kowalevski_theorem), but as Willie points out in his comment we don't need the full force of that theorem in this case.

Differentiating the differential equation with respect to $x$ yields

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\def\part#1#2#3{\frac{\partial^2#1}{\partial#2\partial#3}}\def\par#1#2{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}\par{}t\par Xx
&=&
\par{}x\par Xt
\\
&=&
\par{}x\left(X+\sin X^2\right)
\\
&=&
\par Xx+2X\par Xx\cos X^2\;.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Since the solution for $x=0$ is $X(t,0)=0$, substituting $x=0$ yields

$$\par{}t\par Xx(t,0)=\par Xx(t,0)\;.$$

For the initial value

$$\par Xx(0,0)=\left.\par{}xX(0,x)\right|_{x=0}=1\;,$$

the solution to this differential equation is

$$\par Xx(t,0)=\mathrm e^t\;.$$

Comment: I think the total derivative condition is meant to signify that this is a single ordinary differential equation parametrised by initial data. For this smooth dependence on initial condition does not even require Cauchy-Kowalevskaya. One can estimate it directly: [Andrey Rekalo gave an outline on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/18976/smooth-dependence-of-odes-on-initial-conditions/21622#21622).

Comment: @Willie: I see; thanks for the explanation and the link. The notations I've seen for parameterized functions are $X_{x_0}(t)$ and $X(t;x_0)$, with the parameters separated by a semicolon.

Comment: yes, the subscript and semicolon notations are much better. But in the context of the question the OP is likely not aware of the difference.

Comment: @Willie: By the way, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sofia_Kovalevskaya) says that Sofia Kovalevskaya herself used the name Kowalevski for her academic publications.

Comment: @joriki: I've long given up on the proper spelling of Kowalevski. There are just too many versions floating around in the literature! `:)`