# Finding derivative of solution to ODE with respect to initial condition: bivariate case

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have the following system: $$\begin{cases} \dot{x} =y^2 \\
\dot{y}=x^3 \end{cases}$$
I would like to find the derivative of the solution with respect to the initial conditions, along the solutions $(x(t),y(t)) \equiv 0$. First of all I would like to write the actual equation I need to solve. In this multivariate case, if we write the system $X(t)=(x(t),y(t))$, then we are interested in $\frac{\partial X}{\partial X_0}$. Here also, in vector notation: $\dot{X}=(\dot{x},\dot{y})=(y^2,x^3)$

I have a theorem at my disposal stating that our function of interest($\frac{\partial X}{\partial X_0}$) satisfies:\begin{align}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial X}{\partial X_0} = \frac{\partial \dot{X}}{\partial X}(t,X)\frac{\partial X}{\partial X_0} \quad \quad (1)\end{align}

In this case I imagine that $\frac{\partial X}{\partial X_0}$ is also some bivariate vector. In the univariate case what I usually do is take the right most term in the right hand side to the left hand side, so that we clearly have the derivative of $\log$ of the solution. In turn the term that remains in the RHS, i.e. $\frac{\partial X}{\partial X_0}$ is a straightforward derivative. I guess my concrete question is, how do you write $(1)$ in "coordiante form"? I have checked this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114272/compute-partial-derivative-w-r-t-initial-condition) but I am not able to rewrite $\dot{X}$ as a function of $X$. Any hints are appreciated!

My guess: $\frac{\partial \dot{X}}{\partial X}=\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 2y \\ 3x^2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, so that along solution $X(t) \equiv 0$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \bigg( \frac{\partial X}{\partial X_0} \bigg)= 0$, and hence $\frac{\partial X}{\partial X_0}=I_2$, where $I_2$ is the identity two by two matrix.

Comment: Yes, that looks correct.